# Tab completion for custom path

Tags: shell, emacs, path, elisp, tab-completion

Emacs shell mode tab completion (`comint-dynamic-complete`) is working for commands that are built-in to linux, but it does not seem to detect my original commands whose path is specified in `~/.bashrc`. How can I make `comint-dynamic-complete` look for such commands? I use emacs 23.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shell mode, it looks for directories specified in `exec-path`, which is initialized based on the environment variable `PATH` when Emacs is started. You can overwrite either or both of those in your `.emacs` ([ref](http://www.linux-france.org/article/appli/emacs/manuel/html/shell.html)). [This page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecPath) shows you how to override either of those two variables:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/sw/bin"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/sw/bin")))
```

**EDIT:**

[`Powershell.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Powershell.el) might be a better alternative (haven't used it before) to [`comint.el`](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-editor-packages/comint.el). In the source code comments, it claims to search the `exec-path` for one of the functions, which IMHO should have been done in `comint.el`:

```
;; (defun powershell-dynamic-complete-command ()
;;   "Dynamically complete the command at point.
;; This function is similar to `comint-dynamic-complete-filename', except that it
;; searches the commands from powershell and then the `exec-path' (minus the
;; trailing Emacs library path)  for completion
;; candidates.
```

Have a read in the [source code comments](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Powershell.el) starting with "Notes on TAB for completion."

Comment: I tried both, but they did not work. Do these work for tab completion, not just for command execution?

Comment: @sawa, I just took a look how this method is implemented, and was surprised that it didn't use either of the two variables... I guess the `Powershell.el` is probably a better alternative (see my edit).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`shell-command`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/emacs-goodies-el/trunk/view/head:/elisp/emacs-goodies-el/shell-command.el)

```
(require 'shell-command)
(shell-command-completion-mode)
```